# Unable to get transition effect when using display block

Tags: css, transition

I'm animating a menu from showing 1 item to multiple but I can't get a transition as soon as I add `display: block;`, which I need so that the hidden elements doesn't take up the space. Using `visibility` instead doesn't work since that takes up space. How can I fix this?

```
.feed-menu {
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.feed-menu:hover .feed-menu-item {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
.feed-menu > .feed-menu-item {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
                    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.feed-menu > .feed-menu-item.selected {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/9yxr5bap/3/

Comment: @SoorajChandran .feed-menu-item needs a display: none; or it will still take up space but not be visible, look at the fiddle and you'll get it

Comment: your question says adding `display:block` stops the transition effect. Isn't that `display:none` instead ? That is my confusion

Comment: @SoorajChandran Well it's both, since both has to be used. It has to go from display: none; to display: block; which doesn't work with the transition of width and opacity.